# How can I write code that will run every 30 minutes even if my app is closed in React native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In React native, I need to write a code that will run every 30 minutes even if my application is closed. For both android and ios platforms. how can I do this?

I tried react-native-background-fetch package. but it was not working on ios.

Comment: what type of task you need to run?

Comment: Hello. I want to write the current location of my user to firebase every 30 minutes.

Comment: I don't think that seems a good practice. Google is quite strict with when and how the user location should be taken and that could ban you from the play store. You should check alarms and/or workmanager if you still want to do that.

Comment: For iOS you will need "always" location permission and to activate the location background mode. I suggest you use "significant location change" monitoring. When you get a location update you can determine if it is more than 30 minutes since you last updated your server or you can just update every time.

Comment: You can't. There's no such thing as deterministic scheduling based on time in iOS (for when your app is not in the foreground). You can register for significant location changes as Paulw11 has mentioned.

Comment: In case of ```Android native``` you will need to use ```WorkManager``` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/. In case of ```IOS``` and ```ReactNative``` I can not suggest you anything here.

Comment: Thanks your feedback. So with react-native-geolocation library, can I track the location change even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can't do it directly but we can do it indirectly with notifications help, follow my step

**Step 1:** Create a Firebase cron who sends you a notification in every 30mins.

check this [cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)  [schedule-functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd)

**Step 2:** Setup firebase in react native [firebase setup](https://rnfirebase.io/)

npm install @react-native-firebase/app
npm install @react-native-firebase/messaging
npm install react-native-invoke-app

**Step 3:** Implement Headless JS - is a way to run tasks in JavaScript while your app is in the background.
and add required permission in android xml file

Android permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

add the below mentioned code in the index.js file of your project.

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import React from "react";
import invokeApp from 'react-native-invoke-app';

const firebaseListener = async (remoteMessage) => {
     invokeApp(); // open app
};

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(firebaseListener);

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```